# A sequence of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and bounded; $u_k(x)\rightarrow u_{\ast}(x)$ a.e. in $\Omega$; $f''(u)\geq0$ and $f(u)<0$ for all $u\in\mathbb{R}$. Then do we have
$$
\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty} \int_{\Omega} f(u_k)\,dx
\geq 
\int_{\Omega} \liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty} f(u_k)\,dx
?
$$

Answer (score 1):

You even have $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \int_{\Omega} f(u_k)\,dx
 = 
\int_{\Omega} \liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty} f(u_k)\,dx
$$
without  assuming anything about the convergence of $u_k$. Reason: the assumptions $f''\ge 0$ and $f<0$ imply that $f$ is a constant function.
(Being convex, $f$ stays above its tangent line at every point; but since $f<0$, the tangent line must be horizontal.)